# Process a simple text file in parallels using OpenMP

Tags: c++, multithreading, text-files, openmp

I have a task - I need to write an OpenMP program which should do:

1. Open text file in 2 and then 4 threads.
2. Do some basic processing like count letters, punctuation symbols, words, and write out it in console.
3. I MUST use OpenMP loops.

UPD: I re-re-write whole thing from the scratch, and added "tmpresult" variable which is counting chars in each chunk of chars, as they are being processed. Since "tmpresult" (Total symbols in file) is always equal file length, i assume that inconsistency in counting letters is not result of some symbols being cut off when i breaking file into chunks. Because total file length is equal total symbols count. But then what can cause those inconsistencies?

Output examples:

```
Total threads used 2 
Total symbols in file TinyText2.txt = 9075 
Total symbols without white spaces = 7905 
Total punctuation symbols = 156 

Total threads used 4 
Total symbols in file TinyText2.txt = 9075 
Total symbols without white spaces = 7905 
Total punctuation symbols = 155 

Total threads used 6 
Total symbols in file TinyText2.txt = 9075 
Total symbols without white spaces = 7905 
Total punctuation symbols = 155 

Total threads used 8 
Total symbols in file TinyText2.txt = 9075 
Total symbols without white spaces = 7904 
Total punctuation symbols = 155
```

Code of my program:

```cpp
void* LettersCounter(const string inFileName, int threads) {

    ifstream pFile(inFileName);
    string s = inFileName;
    int numThreads = threads;
    long charsCounter = 0;
    long punctCounter = 0;
    pFile.seekg(0, ios_base::end);
    long length = pFile.tellg();
    pFile.seekg(0, ios_base::beg);
    long lettersCount[numThreads];
    long punctCount[numThreads];
    long chunkSize = length / numThreads;
    char buffer[numThreads][chunkSize];
    long tmp[numThreads];
    long tmpresult = 0;
    for (int z = 0; z <numThreads; z++){
        tmp[z] = 0;
        lettersCount[z]=0;
        punctCount[z]=0;
    }

    #pragma omp parallel for shared(charsCounter, lettersCount, punctCount) private (pFile)

    for (int j = 0; j < numThreads; j++) {
        int currentThread = omp_get_thread_num();
        if (currentThread < numThreads-1) {
        ifstream pFile(s);
        pFile.seekg (currentThread*chunkSize , ios_base::beg);
        pFile.read(buffer[j], chunkSize);
        pFile.seekg (0 , ios_base::beg);
        pFile.close();
        for (int i = 0; i < chunkSize; i++) {

                if (isgraph(buffer[j][i])) {
                    lettersCount[j]++;
                }

                if (buffer[j][i] != 0) {
                    tmp[j]++;
                                }
                if (ispunct(buffer[j][i])) {
                    punctCount[j]++;
                }
    }} else {

    ifstream pFile(s);
    pFile.seekg (currentThread*chunkSize , ios_base::beg);
    long curPosition = pFile.tellg();
    pFile.seekg (0 , ios_base::end);
    long fileLenght = pFile.tellg();
    long finalChunkSize = fileLenght - curPosition;
    pFile.seekg (curPosition , ios_base::beg);
    char finalBuffer[finalChunkSize];
    pFile.read(finalBuffer, finalChunkSize);
    pFile.seekg (0 , ios_base::beg);
    pFile.close();
    for (int i = 0; i < finalChunkSize; i++) {

                if (isgraph(finalBuffer[i])) {
                    lettersCount[j]++;
                }

                if (finalBuffer[i] != 0) {
                    tmp[j]++;
                                }

                if (ispunct(finalBuffer[i])) {
                    punctCount[j]++;
                }
            }

    }}

    for (int z = 0; z <numThreads; z++){

            charsCounter = charsCounter + lettersCount[z];
            punctCounter = punctCounter + punctCount[z];
            tmpresult = tmpresult + tmp[z];
        }
    printf("Total threads used %li \n", threads);
    printf("Total symbols in file %s = %li \n",s.c_str(), tmpresult);
    printf("Total symbols without white spaces = %li \n", charsCounter);
    printf("Total punctuation symbols = %li \n", punctCounter);
    pFile.close();
}
}

int main() {LettersCounter("TinyText2.txt", 4);}
```

Comment: As background (i.e. I'm not answering your specific question!) you might like my blog post about almost exactly this problem at https://cpufun.substack.com/p/processing-a-file-with-openmp

Comment: I did read it already, but the content of this post is a bit too complicated for me. I just need to find a way to break a file into chunks equal numbers of threads. But when I just divide total length of file by number of threads I getting different results depending on numbers of threads. Once i figure it out, then i could ,move to something more advanced.

Comment: I must have missed something here but I don't see any OpenMP into your code. No parallel region, no pragma, no data sharing attribute clause... How is that supposed to work?

Comment: The plan which i outlined in my post. 1. Figure out why the count is off in "bare-bone no OpenMP mode. 2. Add OpenMp operators after, the base program is working. Basically i should rename the thread into "how to split the file in equal chunks". But since i need it for OpenMP task for my Uni, i decided to mention it in case some one would have related suggestion.

Comment: Are you sure you have to *read* a single file in parallel? The hardware is certainly serial here, and any attempt to access a file in parallel should only slow the thing down. Perhaps your professor wants you only to *process* the contents of a file in parallel?